# Deleting a dynamically allocated jagged array

Tags: c++, pointers, memory, delete-operator, jagged-arrays

I have an array of pointers that point to arrays of ints.
I have made a hard coded array of ints (check 'array' below) and I want to insert it into the array of pointers (check 'bar' below), as far as I can tell, it is still an array of pointers that point to arrays of ints.

It compiles fine; no warnings.
It runs fine; and closes fine;
Until at least, I introduce the currently commented out delete statement in the destructor.

I imagine my compiler would make a better destructor at this point, but I'm interested as to what I'm doing wrong. The terminal window just throws out a gigantic memory map; and googling and searching SO didn't help much.

```
class foo {
    public:
    int **bar;
    int aSize;

    //CONSTRUCTOR
    foo(int aSize) {
        this->aSize = aSize;
        bar = new int*[aSize];
        for (int i=0;i<aSize;i++) {
            bar[i] = new int[aSize + i];
            for (int j=0;j<(aSize + i);j++) {
                bar[i][j] = 0;
            }
        }
        }
    void myfunc(int *pointer) {
        bar[0] = pointer;
    }
    ~foo() {
        for (int i=0;i<aSize;i++) {
            //delete[] bar[i];
        }
        delete[] bar;
    }
};
int main() {
    foo *obj = new foo(5);

    int array[] = {1,2,3,4};

    obj->myfunc(array);

    delete obj;
    return 0;
};
```

I know I've probably done something tragic; I just don't know what it is yet.
There is a reason why I am not using STL or other templates, it is simply because I'm interested in learning this.
Maximum criticism appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `myfunc` function takes in a pointer, and then sets `bar[0]` to that memory address.  In your example code, you pass it the address of `array`, which is an automatic (stack) variable.  The destructor then attempts to `delete[] bar[0]`, which points to a *stack variable*.  This is completely [undefined behavior](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior), and the reason your program is crashing.  You can't `delete[]` a stack array.  You can only `delete[]` an array which was allocated using `new[]`.

Also, the `myfunc` function is always going to leak memory, because `bar[0]` points to a heap-allocated array.  When you set `bar` to a different memory address without first `delete[]`ing the previous address, you are leaking memory.

Comment: Right, crap, obvious answer... damn the hot weather. Thanks.
Changing int i=0 to i=1 fixed it.

Comment: Hot weather? [I envy you.](http://www.weather.com/weather/today/New+York+NY+USNY0996?from=search_city "I envy you.")

Comment: You can only `delete[]` an array allocated using `new[]`, not `new`. Minor nitpick.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is calling `myfunc`. In that function, you are replacing a pointer (`bar[0]`) that your class thinks it owns. Your `obj` destructor will then consequently try to run `delete[]` on your `array[]` in `main`, which probably causes your crash **and** leaves your original `bar[0]` dangling.